# How do you create an io.Reader which streams the contents of a wrapped io.Reader through url.QueryEscape?

Tags: go

Given an `io.Reader`, how would one go about wrapping the reader in a `io.Reader` which when read would produce the contents of the underlying reader as if passed through `url.QueryEscape`?

The following produces the panic `panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:513] with capacity 512` when provided an appropriately sized input.

```golang
type queryEscapeReader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (q *queryEscapeReader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := q.r.Read(p)
    if err != nil {
        return n, err
    }

    escaped := url.QueryEscape(string(p[:n]))
    copy(p, []byte(escaped))

    return len(escaped), nil
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do this via a reader? Can you read the whole input first, escape it, and create another reader on the escaped bytes? There is no guarantee that if the caller calls read with small buffers you will have perfectly aligned data, so you may not be able to correctly escape it.

Comment: I'm hoping to make this work with a reader in a buffered manner. I know that reading the full contents into memory, passing through `url.QueryEscape`, and then wrapping in a reader is an option but it's one I'm looking to avoid in the interface I'm creating. The lack of guarantee around data alignment seems to be the issue but was curious if there was a workaround for that which I was missing.

Comment: Also, QueryEscape may produce more bytes than the input. You have to account for that. Either read everything, escape, and then return a reader, or you need to implement a state machine and implement QueryEscape manually.

Comment: Decoding in chunks w/ url.QueryEscape  does not handle the case where an escaped byte spans a chunk boundary.  You need to write your own decoder.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue in the code relates to the fact that `QueryEscape` function can return more bytes than original `p` slice contains. More detailed description of encoding can be found in [RFC 3986: 2.1.  Percent-Encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1)

There are at least two options to solve the issue: you can read from `io.Reader` less bytes than `p` slice length or you can use internal buffer to save bytes from `escaped` slice beyond the length of `p` slice.

While the first one solution can looks easier you should be aware that escaped sequence length can be hardly predictable. For example ([Go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/rz_Hwc9JAAu)):

```
Original strings:
English: Hello, World!
Chineese: 你好世界!

Escaped strings:
English: Hello%2C+World%21 (originalLen=13, escapedLen=17)
Chineese: %E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%21 (originalLen=13, escapedLen=39)
```